# Constraint on class type parameters to say types must not be equal?

Tags: c#, operators, type-constraints

I wondered if there's any type constraint in C# .NET that states that one type parameter doesn't equal another type parameter; something like this...

```
public class FooBar<TA,TB> where TA notequalto TB
```

The reason I want to do this is so that I can create 2 addition operators as per the following...

```
public class FooBar<TA,TB> where TA notequalto TB
{
    public static TA operator +(TB b, FooBar<TA,TB> fooBar)
    {
        return fooBar.Foo(b);
    }

    public static TB operator +(TA a, FooBar<TA,TB> fooBar)
    {
        return fooBar.Bar(a);
    }

    public TA Foo(TB b) { ... }

    public TB Bar(TA a) { ... }
}
```

The problem I face is that if TA = TB, it would be ambiguous in terms of which operator should be called, and thus whether Foo() or Bar() should be called!  Although it's not essential, I wish to be able to implement this if possible...

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such constraint in C# - and I wouldn't *expect* there to be one in the future, given that it's of fairly limited use. (This isn't a situation that comes up terribly often in my experience.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems "unnatural" that your class cannot be used just because TA = TB.

For me the natural is that, in addition to your class define a "same type" version of your class as:

> public class FooBar < T>  {
>
> ```
> public static T operator +(T b, FooBar<T> fooBar)
> {
>     return fooBar.Foo(b);
> }
>
> public T Foo(T b) { ... }
> ```
>
> }

to use when TA = TB (in a similar way as exists non-generic verions of some classes).

Comment: The problem is, the class in question is a codec, which contains an Encode method and a Decode method, where the 2 type parameters supplied are the types that the codec works with; in other words, we encode TA to TB, or we decode TB to TA. I wish to implement an operator so that we can say "TA = TB + Codec<TA,TB>" (which will decode TB to TA) or "TB = TA + Codec<TA,TB>" (which will encode TA to TB). Of course, supplying TA = TB will 'break' the class.

Comment: I should also add that this class is going to be part of a library which will be used by other developers, so I can't ensure they'll not use "TA = TB".

Comment: @Lee.J.Baxter: It's pretty easy to enforce such constraints at runtime.  Not idea, but that and documentation should make things pretty clear.  All that being said, I find it incredibly confusing that want to use `TA = TB+Codec<TA,TB>` rather than `TA = Codec<TA,TB>.Decode(TB);` If you want to be able to concatenate encodes/decodes, I would rather that you overload adding codecs together than decode operations (e.g., `Codec<TA,TB>+Codec<TB,TC>=Codec<TA,TC>` or `Codec<TA,TB>.Add(Codec<TB,TC>).Decode(TC)`, if you want something more fluent.

Comment: @Brian: I wanted the operator as a sort of shortcut; it's not an addition in a literal sense, but more "a coded value plus a codec gives you a decoded value" and vise-versa. I have quite a few examples of this "object arithmetic" in my code.

Comment: When I (as someone unfamiliar with your library) read code using your library, it it is not immediately obvious what addition actually does.  I would prefer to force anyone using your library to actually type out a few extra characters, rather than allowing unnecessary library-specific idioms.  I'll forgive such idioms if they make code easier to read/write, but saving a few characters of typing is insufficient justification for operator overloading.  At best, the only thing you're actually providing is a poor man's fluent interface.